# Unable to start mysql after deleting all the users and reinstalling all mysql package

Tags: mysql

I know the subject been mentioned plenty of times, however I have done extensive research and I am still unable to connect.

Need advice on how to either fix or reinstalling (which I have already done) mysql and I still can not connect to mysql with this message appearing primarily:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (sometimes its YES sometimes is NO)
```

Briefly:

I have deleted all the users, including root (why not ;) !)
to have a nice start.

Installed Dbeaver and Workbench.

Done most things from around 5-7 sources/advices online.

Finally, loosing faith I have removed and reinstalled.

```
sudo apt-get (remove/install) mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common mysql-workbench
```

Things tried:

```
service mysql restart --skip-grant-tables
```

then trying to

```
mysql -u root
```

or

```
mysql -u root -p
```

In between I have done

```
systemctl restart mysql-server
```

many times

Also after restarting grant tables I have tried:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('mypassword') WHERE User='root';
```

One advice recommended dangerous solution of adding a file with root and password details to /root/.my.cnf which I have done according to advice. No results.

I then find an advice to add root and password details to

```
/etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

which failed. Well know error appear:

```
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
```

Now I keep trying:

```
sudo mysqladmin -u root password root
```

and different verision of that

I also keep trying:

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
```

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

This "using password: YES/NO" is confusing for me as I do not know what does it mean. Is there a password or do I need a passoword. I am guessing it describe the fact.

I wonder if editing my.cnf is still the solution as when "sudo updatedb && locate my.cnf" it gives me three locations:

```
/etc/alternatives/my.cnf
/etc/mysql/my.cnf
/etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback
/var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/my.cnf
```

and I only add the user and password in the second one (just guessing :) )

Workbench displays:

```
"Your connection attempt failed for user 'root' from your host to server at localhost:3306:
  Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"
```

Other commands found online:

```
mysql -u root mysql
```

By the way. Does someone could recommend some short tutorial on how to handle the complexity of starting database, how to connect to database, short description of how workbench work in context of my sql, what is the process of starting up with mysql? Dealing with internet? etc?

Thanks a lot for advices.

Kind regards,

eager

other commands tried:

```
sudo mysql -> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

sudo mysql -u root ->ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Comment: At this point, I'd purge (not remove) the whole `mysql` package and start anew.

Comment: Done with commands from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10853004/removing-mysql-5-7-completely

Comment: `sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common` ... I don't see the `--purge` flag on your question. Is that what you've tried?

Comment: Done it with purge, which made difference. Please check the commands on the most upvoted answer in the link above(not questions commands). Seems like pretty good uninstaller.